# How to calculate the minimum and maximum length of the 6th sample, using only measurement data of the first 5 samples?

Tags: inference

1. I have a sack of 1000 sticks.
2. The length of the sticks are normally distributed.
3. I randomly take out 5 sticks and measure them to be [40; 30; 60; 20; 30] mm long.
4. How can I now calculate, with a confidence interval of 99%, the minimum and maximum length of the sixth stick?

I have managed to calculate the population mean standard deviation accurately using t-table but it really doesn't help me here.

Comment: @AryaMcCarthy Yes, 99% confidence interval, thanks!

Comment: @Arya You *don't* mean a confidence interval: this is a *prediction interval.*  The two are [distinct concepts](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22prediction+interval%22+confidence).

Comment: Oof, thanks for educating me!